# Combination Problem on white table

Tags: probability, combinations

Question : How many ways are there to choose 3 cells from a 4x4 table such that any two chosen cells do not belong to the same row nor the same column?

What have i done so far :

choosing $1$ from $16$ cells, each giving remaining $9$ cells option, so my equation would be $$(16)(9)(4)=576$$
which my answer was obviously false since $16C3=560$

Please explain where did I go wrong?
What shall be the correct approach to this answer?

Comment: Hint: How many ways are there to choose a given set of three cells that satisfy the constraint?

Comment: Also, 16C3 is irrelevant here, since it does not take the constraint of no common rows or columns into consideration, and hence overcounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are some double countings in your method.

In the same shape, the method includes $3!$ counts, so my opinion is to divide it into $3!$.